# Jquery and CSS3 Rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, delay

I could really use some help! I am trying to create rotating scroller effect using jquery and CSS3. I would like to run the following in sequence with a delay between each one:

Javascript:

```
$('#scroll-script')
.removeClass().addClass('slide-one')
DELAY
.removeClass().addClass('slide-two')
DELAY
.removeClass().addClass('slide-three')
DELAY
.removeClass().addClass('slide-four')
DELAY
```

HTML:

```
<div id="scroll-script" class="slide-one"></div>
```

Just starting out with Jquery, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what has CSS3 to do with your question? What kind of *efx* are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to achieve a similar effect to the slider that apple has on their iphone page (http://www.apple.com/iphone/). The responses so far have worked perfectly and I am very close :) I am using the css3 rotate and transition styles to create the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once:

```
var i = 0;
delay = 1000;
var el = $('#scroll-script');
var classes = ['slide-one', 'slide-two', 'slide-three', 'slide-four'];

var interval = setInterval(function () {
  el.removeClass().addClass(classes[i]);
  i += 1;
  if (i >= classes.length) clearInterval(interval);
}, delay);
```

In circle:

```
var i = 0;
delay = 1000;
var el = $('#scroll-script');
var classes = ['slide-one', 'slide-two', 'slide-three', 'slide-four'];

var interval = setInterval(function () {
  el.removeClass().addClass(classes[i]);
  i = (i + 1) % 4;
}, delay);
```

Comment: Thank you - it is working perfectly! I Don't think I would ever have figured that out. Is there a simple way to make it repeat?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.animate` for that..
these are some link that will help you out!

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/28/rotating-image-slider/

Answer (score 0):

```
//wrap in a function to provide closure on following vars
//this will prevent them from being in the global scope and
//potentially colliding with other vars
(function () {
    var sub = 0,
        delay = 500, //500 ms = 1/2 a second
        scrollScript = $('#scroll-script'),
        slides = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
        handle;

    //calls the provided anonymous function at the interval delay
    handle = setInterval(function () {
        scrollScript.removeClass().addClass('slide-' + slides[sub]);
        sub += 1;

        // test to see if there is another class in the sequence of classes
        if (!slides[sub]) {
            //if not halt timed callback
            clearInterval(handle);
        }
    }, delay);
}());
```

To make it circular:

```
//wrap in a function to provide closure on following vars
//this will prevent them from being in the global scope and
//potentially colliding with other vars
(function () {
    var sub = 0,
        delay = 500, //500 ms = 1/2 a second
        scrollScript = $('#scroll-script'),
        slides = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
        handle;

    //calls the provided anonymous function at the interval delay
    handle = setInterval(function () {
        scrollScript.removeClass().addClass('slide-' + slides[sub % slides.length]);
        sub += 1;
    }, delay);
}());
```

Comment: @Speranksy, nothing fundamental, besides the anonymous wrapping